# Supported versions in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Does SQL Server 2014 support lower versions of databases? Can I open and modify a database created by a lower version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore and/or attach a database from a lower version of SQL Server (2005 or newer - 2000 no longer supported) to SQL Server 2014 - yes, no problem.

But once it has been attached/restored, it becomes a SQL Server 2014 database - the internal file structures of the `.mdf` and other files are upgraded to SQL Server 2014 level, and you can never "go back" (e.g. you cannot backup from SQL Server 2014 and then restore in earlier versions)